# QMainWindow set frameSize

Tags: qt, qt4

How do you set the frameSize of a QMainWindow?

To explain what I'm trying to do, the requirement I need to meet is that the height of my program's main window be equal to the screen height minus taskbar; but the width should be considerably less than the screen width on a modern wide screen monitor, so I can't just maximize the window.

I can find the screen height minus taskbar no problem with `QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry()`. Calling `resize`  on the window with this value doesn't work, however; as far as I can tell, `resize` makes the interior take up a certain space, as opposed to making the exterior fit within a certain space. The documentation seems to suggest the relevant window property is `frameSize`, but doesn't provide a direct way of setting it. I can probably do some trial and error feedback between `resize` and `frameSize`, but is there a more elegant/idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that complicated. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html) for a nice diagram. You can use `frameGeometry()` and `geometry()` to get the frame widths (horizontal and vertical), and you can then subtract these from your desired frame size before calling `resize()` (or `setFixedSize()` if that is more appropriate for you).

The only way this can go wrong is if the frame widths change as a result of the resize. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Right, the tricky part is that frameGeometry is not set until after the window is shown for the first time (apparently this isn't an API defect, Qt just doesn't know beforehand because the window frame is drawn by the host operating system). Workaround solution: first time the program runs, display the window as a small box, wait till it connects with a server (so it's a natural jump from the user's perspective) then resize to screen height. Then save the resulting window geometry for subsequent runs.

Comment: OK, I didn't realise that. Your workaround can be made perfectly robust by checking after the resize that the saved frame geometry is still valid. That way, if the user changes the desktop style or whatever, you can just redraw the window accordingly and save the new value for next time.